# In Magento, is it possible to populate your product models from an external API instead of the Magento DB?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I currently have Magento 1.7 CE installed.  I want to use the Magento Product Models, except I want to get the price for the product from an external API (our pricing exists outside of Magento).

I know what I could use the Magento API to import all the prices from our existing database, but our pricing changes very often, and we would then need to maintain two databases.

Basically I'm wondering if there is something in Magento I can overwrite to call our API instead of the DB?

I know how to overwrite the Magento core (creating your own modules and setting up your config.xml with the proper rewrite tag).  I can get this to work by overwriting the Product->getPrice method with a call to our API, but then the API is called everytime Product->getPrice is called.  I would rather inject a call to our API at the time of the object creation (when it calls the database and puts the data into the object), but I'm not familiar enough with magento to know where this happens, or if this is even possible.

Comment: the only answer we can give you right now is: "yes". if you want more help you need to try by yourself and come back here if you have specific problems

Comment: I edited my question to make it a little more clear what I have tried already and what exactly I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can setup a custom module which will include an Observer with a method say updateCatalogPrices(). This method can be run via a scheduled cron in your module:

A rough logic can be:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach $product in $productCollection
$priceFromAPI = ?//your logic to get the price using API
$product->setPrice($priceFromAPI)
        ->save();
```

Cron scheduled will depend upon: 
How often price get updated. 
No. of products in your database.

But for a catalog of 40000+ products, above approach may take upto 1 day or more to complete. Instead of using product model, direct sql queries can be used to reduce the updation time.
I came across one such piece of code that seems to be promising, here's the link http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is a good idea.  My only concern is we have 40,000+ products so we wouldn't be able to run the cron very often, and I'm concerned about stale data.  This gives me something to work with though, thank you!

Comment: Not sure about how & exactly when to trigger that API call to update price for a product when it's object data is loaded or getPrice() is called. My approach can be a plan B, so I edited it to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

using below code you can get product price puting php file in magento root

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
foreach ($collection as $_product)
{
echo $_product->getPrice();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm not asking how to get a product's price, I'm asking how to get a product's price from our third party API instead of the database.